# Enforce child classes to bind to enums for that child only

Tags: java, generics, enums

Let's say I have an

```
abstract class Doctor{ }
```

I want to enforce that any extensions of this abstract class be bound to an explicit list of medical procedures `E extends Enum<E> & Procedures`.

At the same time, I need the binding to be to an enum specifically for the extending class. E.g. I want

```
class Neurosurgeon 
    extends Doctor<E extends Enum<E> & Procedures<Neurosurgeon>{ }
```

At the same time, I want the enum-marking interface to also be tied to a specific extension of `Doctor` when declared. E.g.

```
public enum NeurosurgeryProcedures implements Procedures<Neurosurgeon> { }
```

but not allow

```
public enum NeurosurgeryProcedures implements Procedures<Accounting> { }
```

in other words, `Procedures<? extends Doctor>`

This leads to circular referencing of some sort that is not resolvable by the compiler. Any one have any suggestions how I can enforce these requirements?

Comment: Can you explain/demonstrate why the circular referencing is necessary?

Comment: @paulBellora Basically for each child class, there should be an associated list of enums specifically for that child class, and I want to ensure that only those are bound to each other; two parallel type hierarchies that are supposed to have a one-to-one correspondance.

Comment: I understand that but I'm trying to get at *why* that's needed. For example, why not just `Neurosurgeon extends Doctor<NeurosurgeryProcedures>` and `NeurosurgeryProcedures` implements `Procedures` (non-generic)? Consider showing some example implementation code that would rely on the two-way generic relationship.

Comment: @PaulBellora Because then there's nothing preventing someone from defining a `NeurosurgeryProcedures` enum that implements some other set of Procedures. I'd like to in another part of the application, work on various procedures of all kinds, both medical and non-medical, but want to in these definitions restrict the binding to procedures related to doctors... does that make sense...?

Comment: anishthecoder's answer is very clever. but it may not allow a neurosurgeon to perform a gp's procedures. you may need the constructors to take a list of enum classes. you could type the different enums by a marker interface, so that accounting does not sneak in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is possible with the correct generic parameters.

Define the doctor as follows:

```
abstract class Doctor<
    D extends Doctor<D, P>,
    P extends Enum<P> & Procedures<P, D>> {...}
```

Define the `enum` marking procedures for a specific doctors as follows:

```
interface Procedures<
    P extends Enum<P> & Procedures<P, D>,
    D extends Doctor<D, P>> {...}
```

Then, a child class of `Doctor` will be required to specify a specific set of procedures for that child class. Thus, a child class for a neurosurgeon,

```
class Neurosurgeon extends
    Doctor<Neurosurgeon, NeurosurgeryProcedures> {...}
```

requires neurosurgery procedures specific for that type of doctor:

```
enum NeurosurgeryProcedures
    implements Procedures<NeurosurgeryProcedures, Neurosurgeon> {...}
```

I think this properly ties child class definitions with enums specific to that child class.